# Where is the 'Hostname' of my Tridion CM taken from for filtered publishing?

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, database

I have set up [Publisher filtering](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-863D3D2F-380D-48B3-A4B5-E195FDE7A6A8#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-655433CE-6AB3-4A21-AE4C-A263A92C9FF9.xml&docid=GUID-655433CE-6AB3-4A21-AE4C-A263A92C9FF9&inner_id=&tid=5dea0b7e-ab96-477e-ad5e-83eb9d7e8d68&query=mmc%2520publications%2520publisher&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-655433CE-6AB3-4A21-AE4C-A263A92C9FF9&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dmmc%2520publications%2520publisher&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1431608399802&currentQuery=mmc%2520publications%2520publisher&currentScope=) based on the **Hostname** of the Content Manager that the items were published from.

I have this working using the following settings:

[image]

However, I am wondering where this Hostname is configured/specified on the Tridion Content Manager server.

I initially thought that it would be the CME's Hostname (within IIS), but the  CME is actually accessed using http://Tridion2013SP1.customer-name.com (although http://Tridion2013SP1 is also set up as a 'binding' in IIS and is the machine name).

I had to find out the hostname used from the `QUEUE_MESSAGES` table within the Content Manager database.

[image: Screenshot of the Tridon_cm database query]

Where is this hostname set / configured?

Is it editable?

Is this the machine name of the Content Manager server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this is the Windows [hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) (i.e. Computer name), rather than the CME's hostname within IIS.

> In computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)) is a label that is assigned to a device connected to a computer network and that is used to identify the device in various forms of electronic communication

[image: Computer name on Windows GUI]

This can also be found using the `ipconfig /all` command...

[image: Ipconfig command line on Windows for host name]

Comment: A Windows computer has one active "computer name", but can be known by several hostnames on the network. For easy access, check the COMPUTERNAME environment variable. Tridion uses the computername for queue registration. The hostname bindings in IIS are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @DominicCronin, I'll make sure to check that environment variable in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check it by typing "hostname" in the command prompt -

[image]